# Apex Trigger on Campaign (Create automatic welcome email)

Tags: apex, trigger

I created an app for the Sales team, exclusive for expos or campaigns, Now i want to create a trigger, when the contact is created if new sent a welcome email with some information that was recollected in the expo visit, how can i do this? I already have the email template ready, but I can´t create trigger

Comment: There must be a way to do this without code, no? Process builder? You want to be really judicious with sending emails to campaign responses as the outbound email limits are very low.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are bound by your requirements to do this via trigger, but generally it would be considered best practice to do this through declarative steps:

From the setup page, in the sidebar, click `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Workflow Rules`

Click `New Workflow Rule` on the `Contact` object. `For Evaluate the rule when a record is:` you will want to say `Created`.

From there, set your entry criteria (perhaps `CreatedDate = TODAY()`). Save & Next.

You will then add a `Workflow Action`, for this it would be a `New Email Alert`. Select your email template and choose the target (likely an `Email Field` of the `Contact`.)